# how to replace characters in pandas dataframe columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Hi i have a dataframe with column name that I would like to change. They are:

```
df.columns

Index(['ID_Produit', 'cTypeFinancialItem', 'cClasseFinancialItem',
       'sTypeFinancialObject', 'checkbox', 'sNom', 'sURL', 'sNomManager',
       'sNomTypeFinancialObject', 'sGroupeCat_Specific_Dynamic',
       'sGroupeCat_rng1', 'sCodeISIN', 'nVL', 'sCurrency', 'nStarRating',
       'nScore', 'nRetYTD', 'nRet1a', 'nRet3a', 'nRet5a', 'nRet1c', 'nRet3c',
       'nRet1j', 'nRet1m', 'nRet3m', 'nRet6m', 'nRet5c', 'nRet8c', 'nVolat1a',
       'nVolat3a', 'nVolat5a', 'nSharpe1a', 'nSharpe3a', 'nSharpe5a',
       'nPerteMax1a', 'nPerteMax3a', 'nPerteMax5a', 'nSortino1a', 'nSortino3a',
       'nSortino5a', 'nIr1A', 'nIr3A', 'nIr5A', 'nMinInvest', 'nFraisGestion',
       'nFraisEntree', 'nFraisSortie', 'dtRet', 'dtRetMonth', 'bFerme',
       'nIntensiteESG', 'nActifEur', 'nActifDiffEUR1m', 'nActifDiffEUR3m',
       'nActifDiffEUR6m', 'nActifDiffEUR1A', 'nActifCompartimentEUR',
       'nActifCompartimentDiffEUR1m', 'nActifCompartimentDiffEUR3m',
       'nActifCompartimentDiffEUR6m', 'nActifCompartimentDiffEUR1A',
       'nCollecteCompartiment1m', 'nCollecteCompartiment3m',
       'nCollecteCompartiment6m', 'nCollecteCompartimentYTD',
       'nCollecteCompartiment1A', 'nCollecteCompartiment3A', 'nCollecteRet1m',
       'nCollecteRet3m', 'nCollecteRet6m', 'nCollecteRetYTD', 'nCollecteRet1A',
       'nCollecteRet3A', 'nCollecteCompartimentRet1m',
       'nCollecteCompartimentRet3m', 'nCollecteCompartimentRet6m',
       'nCollecteCompartimentRetYTD', 'nCollecteCompartimentRet1A',
       'nCollecteCompartimentRet3A', 'isESG', 'sArticleSFDR', 'nIntensiteISR',
       'nESG_Environnement', 'nESG_Social', 'nESG_Gouvernance', 'nNbLabels',
       'sProspectusUrl', 'sUrlMainDocument', 'isMainDocumentAccessible'],
      dtype='object')
```

I would like to replace the 1st character if it is a 's' or 'n' ie 'sNom' will become 'Nom'.

I tried:

```
for col in df.columns:
    df[col] = df[col].apply(lambda x : x[1:] if x.startswith("s") or x.startswith('n') else x)
```

but get an error message

Answer (score 2):

You can try `Index.str.replace`

```py
df.columns = df.columns.str.replace('^(s|n)', '', regex=True)
```

```
print(df.columns)

Index(['ID_Produit', 'cTypeFinancialItem', 'cClasseFinancialItem',
       'TypeFinancialObject', 'checkbox', 'Nom', 'URL', 'NomManager',
       'NomTypeFinancialObject', 'GroupeCat_Specific_Dynamic',
       'GroupeCat_rng1', 'CodeISIN', 'VL', 'Currency', 'StarRating', 'Score',
       'RetYTD', 'Ret1a', 'Ret3a', 'Ret5a', 'Ret1c', 'Ret3c', 'Ret1j', 'Ret1m',
       'Ret3m', 'Ret6m', 'Ret5c', 'Ret8c', 'Volat1a', 'Volat3a', 'Volat5a',
       'Sharpe1a', 'Sharpe3a', 'Sharpe5a', 'PerteMax1a', 'PerteMax3a',
       'PerteMax5a', 'Sortino1a', 'Sortino3a', 'Sortino5a', 'Ir1A', 'Ir3A',
       'Ir5A', 'MinInvest', 'FraisGestion', 'FraisEntree', 'FraisSortie',
       'dtRet', 'dtRetMonth', 'bFerme', 'IntensiteESG', 'ActifEur',
       'ActifDiffEUR1m', 'ActifDiffEUR3m', 'ActifDiffEUR6m', 'ActifDiffEUR1A',
       'ActifCompartimentEUR', 'ActifCompartimentDiffEUR1m',
       'ActifCompartimentDiffEUR3m', 'ActifCompartimentDiffEUR6m',
       'ActifCompartimentDiffEUR1A', 'CollecteCompartiment1m',
       'CollecteCompartiment3m', 'CollecteCompartiment6m',
       'CollecteCompartimentYTD', 'CollecteCompartiment1A',
       'CollecteCompartiment3A', 'CollecteRet1m', 'CollecteRet3m',
       'CollecteRet6m', 'CollecteRetYTD', 'CollecteRet1A', 'CollecteRet3A',
       'CollecteCompartimentRet1m', 'CollecteCompartimentRet3m',
       'CollecteCompartimentRet6m', 'CollecteCompartimentRetYTD',
       'CollecteCompartimentRet1A', 'CollecteCompartimentRet3A', 'isESG',
       'ArticleSFDR', 'IntensiteISR', 'ESG_Environnement', 'ESG_Social',
       'ESG_Gouvernance', 'NbLabels', 'ProspectusUrl', 'UrlMainDocument',
       'isMainDocumentAccessible'],
      dtype='object')
```

Comment: For single characters `^[sn]` also works.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution finally:

```
df = (df.rename({c: c[1:] for c in df.columns if c.startswith('c') or c.startswith('s') or c.startswith('n')},
                         axis='columns')
```

Thanks

Comment: `{... if c[0] in 'csn'}`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can assign the modified column list back to df.columns

```
df.columns = [x[1:].strip() if x.startswith("s") or x.startswith('n') else x for x in df.columns]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`str.lstrip`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.lstrip.html):

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.lstrip('csn')
```

Output:

```
>>> df.columns
Index(['ID_Produit', 'TypeFinancialItem', 'ClasseFinancialItem',
       'TypeFinancialObject', 'heckbox', 'Nom', 'URL', 'NomManager',
       'NomTypeFinancialObject', 'GroupeCat_Specific_Dynamic',
       'GroupeCat_rng1', 'CodeISIN', 'VL', 'Currency', 'StarRating', 'Score',
       'RetYTD', 'Ret1a', 'Ret3a', 'Ret5a', 'Ret1c', 'Ret3c', 'Ret1j', 'Ret1m',
       'Ret3m', 'Ret6m', 'Ret5c', 'Ret8c', 'Volat1a', 'Volat3a', 'Volat5a',
       'Sharpe1a', 'Sharpe3a', 'Sharpe5a', 'PerteMax1a', 'PerteMax3a',
       'PerteMax5a', 'Sortino1a', 'Sortino3a', 'Sortino5a', 'Ir1A', 'Ir3A',
       'Ir5A', 'MinInvest', 'FraisGestion', 'FraisEntree', 'FraisSortie',
       'dtRet', 'dtRetMonth', 'bFerme', 'IntensiteESG', 'ActifEur',
       'ActifDiffEUR1m', 'ActifDiffEUR3m', 'ActifDiffEUR6m', 'ActifDiffEUR1A',
       'ActifCompartimentEUR', 'ActifCompartimentDiffEUR1m',
       'ActifCompartimentDiffEUR3m', 'ActifCompartimentDiffEUR6m',
       'ActifCompartimentDiffEUR1A', 'CollecteCompartiment1m',
       'CollecteCompartiment3m', 'CollecteCompartiment6m',
       'CollecteCompartimentYTD', 'CollecteCompartiment1A',
       'CollecteCompartiment3A', 'CollecteRet1m', 'CollecteRet3m',
       'CollecteRet6m', 'CollecteRetYTD', 'CollecteRet1A', 'CollecteRet3A',
       'CollecteCompartimentRet1m', 'CollecteCompartimentRet3m',
       'CollecteCompartimentRet6m', 'CollecteCompartimentRetYTD',
       'CollecteCompartimentRet1A', 'CollecteCompartimentRet3A', 'isESG',
       'ArticleSFDR', 'IntensiteISR', 'ESG_Environnement', 'ESG_Social',
       'ESG_Gouvernance', 'NbLabels', 'ProspectusUrl', 'UrlMainDocument',
       'isMainDocumentAccessible'],
      dtype='object')
```

Comment: IMO it's ad-hoc and risky decision that's gonna be a source of bugs over time, no?